# Submit form synchronously

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to do something like this: I got form and feedback panel and in one special case after clicking submit button I want a message to be shown in the feedback panel firstly and then after that I want another action (in my case it's searching phrase in log file) to be executed. Because for now when I click submit button then searching starts and when it ends the message in the feedback panel is already shown.

Comment: what have you tried already ? show the code you have worked on....or trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a AjaxLazyLoadPanel to show the results of the search.

```
onSubmit(ART art) {
    infO("Searching..");

    searchResultContainer.addOrReplace(new MySearchResultLazyLoadPanel("result));

    art.add(searchResultContainer);
}
```